# Ionic Sqlite : insert dynamic array into table

Tags: angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to insert an array into my sqlite database. But all the data is getting inserted into the first column. Please help. I already checked these :

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/392

[sqlite3 insert into dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058863/sqlite3-insert-into-dynamic-table)

But not able to solve my problem.

my code is

```
 let insertarr:Array;

for(var i=0;i<this.fullData.length;i++)

{
insertarr = [];
for(var j=0;j<this.fullData[i].length;j++)
{

        insertarr.push(this.fullData[i][j].val);

      }
     alert(insertarr);
      db.executeSql('insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values(?,?,?)', [insertarr]);  
  }
```

When I run the above code col1 is getting populated with the full array. col2 and col3 are populated with null.

Comment: How do you want insert the data?

Comment: I want to insert the array. the array have 3 elements and my table have 3 columns.

Comment: You have an array with 3 element and want to insert each element to a column right?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue. Posting if it helps someone in future.

I changed the arguments of db.executeSql like below:

```
 db.executeSql('insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values('+insertarr+')', {});
```